# Solution explorer window empty when debugging ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

My solution explorer window is fine normally, but empty when I try to debug my MVC application.

I have already deleted the **ComponentModelCache** folder at:

> C:\Users\jmk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

I have also restarted the PC.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, has anybody experienced this before? How do you solve it?

This seems to be for any web project, here is a Gif showing what happens:

[image: Gif showing solution explorer emptying on debug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing Visual Studio's settings:

**First back it all up (thanks to [Stijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247702/stijn) for the suggestion)**

- Tools
- Import & Export Settings
- Export selected environment settings
- Click next and check all settings are selected for export
- Choose backup path and
  export

**Clear the settings**

- Tools
- Import & Export Settings
- Reset all Settings

Close and reopen Visual Studio

Comment: Best to export your current settings first, so you can reapply them when the reset didn't solve the issue.